# `while IFS= read -r` still not preserving whitespace?

Tags: bash

I am trying to preserve all whitespace in an input file during while loop iteration. Here is the file I am working with (file1):

```
a@ubuntu:~$ cat file1
01: a   b   c
02: d   e   f
```

As you can see, I have placed tabs between the characters on each line. I want to keep those tabs on output. I have tried clearing IFS in the while loop like so:

```
while IFS= read -r p; do
    echo $p
done < <(cat file1)
```

The result gets rid of the tabs for some reason even after I clear IFS (I have also tried echo -e):

```
a@ubuntu:~$ sudo bash a.sh
01: a b c
02: d e f
```

However, when I clear IFS outside of the while loop, it works perfectly:

```
IFS=''

while read -r p; do
    echo $p
done < <(cat file1)
```

Here is the output; the tabs are preserved:

```
a@ubuntu:~$ sudo bash a.sh
01: a   b   c
02: d   e   f
```

Why do the tabs fail to be preserved when I clear IFS in the same line as the while loop?

Comment: Why are you using `< <(cat file1)` vs `< file1`?

Comment: Amusing. I had come to know about process redirection much later than I knew of stdin redirect from file. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just quote your variables:

```
while IFS= read -r p; do     
  echo "$p"; 
done < file1
```

Notice that you don't need to use `cat` as well.

Comment: Ugh. Thanks so much. That did it. I knew it was going to be something super simple. Should I always be quoting my variables?

Comment: @orbit - YES!!! You MUST always quote your variables unless you have a very specific reason not to and know EXACTLY what the consequences are.

Comment: @orbit This [link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html) will be helpful!

Comment: @orbit if you want it to be one argument to whatever command, and not split on whitespace, then you should quote it.

Comment: Always quote. If you don't quote, `echo $p` becomes `echo 01:<tab>a<tab>b<tab>c`, which is functionally equivalent to `echo 01: a b c`. Setting `IFS` to null (an empty string) for `echo` won't fix it either because `echo` still receives 4 arguments: '01:', 'a', 'b', and 'c'. By using quotes, you change it into a single argument, so `echo` will print that single argument 100% character for character.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune - well.... echo won't necessarily print 100% character for character. What it WILL print depends on your version of echo. The OP should really use `printf "%s\n" "$p"` instead but then they almost certainly shouldn't be writing this loop in the first place as it's probably completely the wrong approach to do whatever it is they really need to do.

Comment: @EdMorton - thank you for the response. Are you suggesting that printf is always preferred over echo? If so, why? 

Also, my goal was to redirect a command's output to a variable ($p), then read the output line by line to check if the line began with a 2 digit number (regex). If it did, echo that line. This works, but if there are better ways to go about it, I am all ears. Thanks again.

Comment: @orbit - Yes, printf is always preferred over echo for portability and robustness, just google something like "bash printf echo" to see details if you care. The better way to do what you describe is simply `command | grep '^[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]'`. If you want to do more than that and would like help, post a new question describing what you are really trying to do. So far you are almost certainly getting partially correct answers to the wrong questions.